# Prevent IE from storing/caching URL shortcuts

Tags: html, security, internet-explorer, temporary-files

It seems that a shortcut with the destination of the invoking URL is created (cached) in 'Temporary Internet Files' under the user's profile on the local desktop machine.

How can one prevent IE from doing so? It would be even great if it can be somehow controlled by the hosted page itself (may be some  tags in the HTML), rather than users having to configure their IE setup.

Comment: You could add a specific url component that changes per request, thus preventing the browser from understanding each request is the same request.

Comment: You could add a random number at the end of the URL or something each time it loads if you have PHP. But it might also be possible with JS. I don't know about HTML though.

Comment: @Nathan. We have worked it around by adding a random number at the end of the URL, but the ask here is to really prevent those shortcuts from being created (if possible).

Comment: The real question is *why* you want to prevent caching. You can learn more about browser caching here: http://fiddler2.com/redir/?id=httpperf

Comment: Because we have a client that apparently has a problem with it, and no matter what, they refuse to accept that it should be harmless. But anyway, I'm still curious to know if that's possible and how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could prevent it from caching by putting this HTML in your `<head>` tags:

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />
```

Keep in mind that this wont always prevent it from caching but usually does.

You could also use PHP if you wanted, by putting this at the **very top** of your PHP page (if it's PHP) before the opening `<html>` tag:

```
<?php
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
```

*FYI: Cache = Temporary Internet Files (if you didn't know)*

Hope this helps.

---

**Edit:**

So you are using JSP? Please see this page: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0590.html I hope this solves your problem. :)

Comment: I did try the meta tags you mentioned above, but they didn't work out. It would be a JSP, so the PHP headers are out.